# update() with find() in laravel is not working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am new to laravel, I am facing problem while creating generic update function,

code 1: this is not working

```
if ($obj->find($primaryKey)->update($data)){
    return TRUE;
}
else
    return FALSE;
```

code 2: but if i tried this, it is working:

```
if ($obj->where("candidate_id", $primaryKey)->update($data)){
    return TRUE;
}
else
    return FALSE;
```

i want code 1 should work

Comment: and you can also reuturn $obj->find($primaryKey)->update($data); without making that boilerplate

Comment: then what could be the better solution for doing this

Answer (score 2):

Got the solution :

```
if ($obj->where($obj->getKeyName(), $primaryKey)->update($data)){
    return TRUE;
}
else
    return FALSE;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make an educated guess that since Laravel expects the primary key to be `id` and you're using `candidate_id` that you need the set the `$primaryKey` property of your model accordingly.

```
class Candidate extends Model {
    protected $primaryKey = 'candidate_id';
}
```

You also may wish to check to make sure `find()` finds something before committing an update to avoid errors.

```
if ($object = $obj->find($primaryKey)) {
    $object->update($data);
}
```